# Any issues if I typed logo in Word file, but contractor requests .AI file, to construct logo?

Tags: logo

I'm [technophobe, cyberphobe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/175606).  As you see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/153952), I typed my logo in Microsoft Word. Then I screenshot my logo text, and emailed the .JPG to my Contractor. Purpose is to manufacture and emblazon my logo text.

1. But my Contractor still prefers .AI (Adobe Illustrator) file. I asked him why, and he just replied .AI is industry standard and usual business practice. Why else? Do you know other reasons? Why doesn't my .JPG file suffice?
2. Do you foresee any issues if I use some online website to convert my screenshot .JPG to .AI file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To emblazon logo — Must I reveal font to contractor? Or can I just email PDF with logo text?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/153952/to-emblazon-logo-must-i-reveal-font-to-contractor-or-can-i-just-email-pdf-wit)

Comment: @Scott - didn't realize this was a duplicate or just a rewording of the same question asked before, and already closed now.  Think I'm gonna delete my answer and vote to close.

Comment: @Scott No it doesn't. Here I'm asking about .jpg vs. .ai.

Comment: @BillyKerr Can you please UN delete your answer? I want to read it pls. I'm interested in second opinions.

Comment: @asts - no sorry. I won't.  My suggestion was simply to export as PDF from Word. This suggestion is already covered in one of the comments to your other question, also suggested in the accepted answer here.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hmmmm....what's the harm or drawback from un deleting your answer though? I appreciate undeleting pls. I see nothing to lose, and everything to gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not want to be rude, but really trying to help you to get your things done, and done right.

> I'm technophobe, cyberphobe.

No. You want to be cheap. Reading this and the other question, You are trying to "save some dollars" but **this will cost money to someone else**. This is costing money to your contractor to find the font, recreate a poorly made logo, and use it in an application that NEEDS the proper workable file format.

<sub>Right now, there are some people that use this forum, that offers some interesting solutions for free, but some of them are pretty good at what they do and the time to make a personalized advisory will surely pay for a licence. **We all gladly do it, do not get me wrong.** My point is that there is nothing really free in life.</sub>

---

> my Contractor still prefers .AI (Adobe Illustrator) file

He does not prefer it. He NEEDS it or he needs to recreate it. It will probably not be done in front of your eyes, but it MUST be done in order to do anything. And this costs more than a licence from the font.

---

Answering the specific question.

A vector file is a set of instructions of the geometry inside.

The image is a circle with X diameter and Y with. As it is a mathematical expression it can be scaled, and used as instructions to a new part of a process. A 3D image, a print, or a sign.

A Jpg file is just a photo.

---

If you still want to do it yourself:

1. Download Inkscape.
2. Draw the logo.
3. Export it as curves, and send an SVG file.

---

To clarify: AI is a proprietary file format of specific software, Adobe Illustrator, which is the most commonly used program of its kind. It is a vector format.

SVG is a generic file format that can be used in a variety of programs, including Adobe Illustrator. So, if you do not have Adobe Illustrator, SVG is a good option.

A lot of times when someone says "I need AI", in reality, they mean: "I need a vector file format, but I am used to using AI, If you provide me with a good alternative I can use, PDF or SVG, it will be fine". (Some specific times they actually need AI, not on this case)

Other programs use different proprietary file formats, like Corel Draw or Affinity Design, but they can easily export to PDF or SVG.

Comment: Thanks so much! "I do not want to be rude" Don't worry about it. Be direct and blunt. I rather understand you than need to guess you. "Export it as curves, and send a SVG file." But Contractor asked for .AI file, not SVG. Was this a typo?

Comment: SVG isnt entirely optimal because there is a bit of a problem estimating the size of a svg file otherwise fine.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the SVG file format.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask for manufacturing of something then odds are they *need* a vector image. Its not so much about what they want. An ai file, pdf maybe a dxf or a svg should all be fine.

Why? Well, the contractor wants 2 things

1. Make his life easy
2. Ensuring a satisfied client who pays the bill

A jpeg file makes 1. work hard and 2. less likely. So he does the sane thing to asks for a file that most clients would know to deliver. It is common that clients dont know to send right file. But if they had a real logo designed they would have been given a *.ai or *.pdf file that does the job.

But why do they need a vector file, image is a image right. Well, no a raster image like jpeg just describes a surface at a fixed size. But anybody looking to cut something is looking for the edge. And anybody doing anything at scale wouldnt be able to work on a screenshot. Vectors do all of this. At the end of the day the laser, waterjet plasmacutter or NC Mill eats only vectors. So somebody needs to make it so.

Could they do it regardless? Sure. But because quality, really suffers, they dont want to. At the end its your money if you can convince your contractor that you will pay more for a bad job go for it. I wouldn't do it because it would double my workload.

**Point is you can get prime stuff for less effort.**

Do it again in inkscape or illustrator and outline the text now no more font info. Really nobody cares.

Comment: +1 and "Looking for the edge": in layman's terms, scaling a jpeg makes the edges "all jagged" everyone knows that, but if we traced the enlarged image, the cutter will *faithfully reproduce those jagged bits*. On the other hand, vectors are smooth and scale smoothly, so the cuts are smooth.