# If I typed text in Microsoft Word for my logo, does .ai vs. .pdf matter?

Tags: pdf

My Contractor requested the .ai file for [my logo that I typed in Microsoft Word](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/153952/168829). But I'm [technophobe, cyberphobe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/175606). Please try to avoid tech jargon.

Before I spend hours downloading InkScape, and trying to learn how to copy and paste my text from Word to InkScape — I must check if the Contractor loses or suffers anything if I just save my Word file as a PDF and email him the PDF.  On one hand, [jooja answered](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154217/any-issues-if-i-typed-logo-in-word-file-but-contractor-requests-ai-file-to-co/154222#154222)

> An ai file, pdf maybe a dxf or a svg should all be fine.

On other hand, [egypturnash commentated](https://old.reddit.com/r/AdobeIllustrator/comments/b9ebcm/saving_as_a_compatible_pdf_versus_ai/)

> Saving your work as PDFs is not quite as bad an idea as, say, saving your Photoshop documents as JPEGs, but it is a similarly bad idea in my experience. In fact I save all my work as AI files with PDF compatibility turned *off*, and treat PDF the same way as I treat a PNG or JPEG: a format that I export to.
>
> I have found that a file with both PDF and AI data in it is at *least* twice as large as an AI-only file. Often many, many times more if I use anything complex like pattern fills, art brushes, or bitmap effects.
>
> I have also found that sometimes a file will get corrupted such that it loads the PDF half, which loses a lot of data - all those paths with bitmap effects get replaced by embedded, uneditable images; gradients get expanded, color profiles get dropped, etc. If you're only using flat colors right now you won't notice this, but as your practice expands to use more corners of what AI can do, you *will* run into things that PDF saves improperly, and this *will* bite you.
>
> I would *strongly* recommend keeping your work as PDF-incompatible AI files until you absolutely have to export a PDF, and doing your last-minute edits on the AI files, then generating a new PDF.

Who's correct?????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any issues if I typed logo in Word file, but contractor requests .AI file, to construct logo?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154217/any-issues-if-i-typed-logo-in-word-file-but-contractor-requests-ai-file-to-co)

Comment: Stop posting the same question repeatedly.

Comment: PDF is a "wrapper", a container, not a format in itself. That "wrapper" can contain quality artwork or horrible, unusable artwork.

Comment: @Scott NO. STOP falsely flagging my questions as duplicates. That linked question asks about .JPG. Here I'm asking .ai vs. PDF. Did you read my questions at all?

Comment: They are *all* duplicates. If you need to add more information, **edit** your original question, don't post the same question with information merely reworded. And.. for the record, I myself **can't** close your questions.

Comment: @Scott NO THEY AREN'T. RE READ MY QUESTIONS CAREFULLY PLS. The first question is about if Contractor needs to know font. Second is .jpg vs. .ai. This one is .pdf vs. ai.

Comment: They are all the same question... *"How can I **not** provide an AI file even though a contractor is asking for one."* -- Then they just go off into tangents... *"can I provide a jpg?"*, *"Can I provide a PDF?"* -- but it's all the same question.

Comment: Ultimately you would have saved a lot of money and sanity by actually hiring a graphic designer to handle this.

Comment: Sad thing is there are web sites where this could have *literally* been done in 10 minutes for $5 and you'd have an AI file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter. Yes PDF compatibility in AI is largely redundant if the end user is using Illustrator. But then nothing but Illustrator can open it. Being able to embed it is a good thing.

The only reason Illustrator would open PDF variant is if the AI format in the file is is newer than the Illustrator your opening or using a plugin reciever does not have. In which case it wouln't open anything if you didnt embed the PDF.

Its also not corrupted but PDF is really like that, it does not contain AI features. But rather they are expanded to PDF primitives. Thats how its supposed to work.

There are no guarantees, a PDF and AI can contain a jpeg in which case nothing was gained. If you build badly you get bad results.

PS: yes this is sortof the same question.